# Windows remote desktop service running, but not listening on port 3389

Tags: windows, hyper-v, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

I just downloaded and installed Hyper-V Server 2019 from [Microsoft Evaluation Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2019) (version: 1809/10.0.17763.1).
Now I'm not able to connect to this machine (which I named `hypervserver`) using remote desktop.

Routing seems to be fine and pinging works as well, but the RDP port is not reachable:

```
>$ ping hypervserver
Reply from {IP}: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
[...]
>$ telnet hypervserver 3389
Connecting To {IP}...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3389: Connect failed
```

No changes even after disabling firewalls and setting the network category of the used network profiles to `Private`.

I can see that I successfully enabled RDP, because `sconfig.cmd` says:

```
4) Configure Remote Management: Enabled
7) Remote Desktop: Enabled (all clients)
```

Registry keys look good as well:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\fDenyTSConnection = 0
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\fEnableWinStation = 1
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber = 3389
```

Service seems to be running:

```
PS >$ Get-Service -Name termservice -ComputerName hypervserver
Status  Name        DisplayName
------  ----        -----------
Running termservice Remote Desktop Services
```

However, noone seems to be listening on port 3389:

```
>$ netstat -ano | findstr LISTEN | findstr :3389
>$
```

I have a standard setup with an ordinary (and single) ethernet network interface configured to get its IP using DHCP.
Neither rebooting nor restarting the service has helped.
Event log does not contain any errors.

What else could be the problem?
Shouldn't this work out of the box?

Comment: Did you check your (Windows) firewall settings?

Comment: @eKKiM I disabled the firewall using `Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled False` in PowerShell. I did not mention it because I thought it doesn't matter unless some process is actually listening to the specific port.

Comment: It seems you have everything configured correctly. I'd use nmap to perform a full scan in the server since netstat it's useful but not the same thing. It could be also some issue with the evaluation version, just saying.

Comment: Did another test on bare metal. Same result.
@HumbertoCastellon nmap also suggested that only TCP ports 135 and 2179 are open, but no port offering RDP. I'm also not sure why the (non-expiring) image downloaded from the evaluation center would be any different because it's the 2019 RTM version number already and Hyper-V Server is free anyways.

Comment: Did Event Log says something after service restart? If it tries to bind port and fails, it have to write an error to log.

Comment: @warder No errors in event log.

Comment: Some registry values have both policy and non-policy locations:

 `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services!fDenyTSConnections`

Comment: @GregAskew The key `Terminal Services` in `Windows NT` does not exist so I assume there's no policy override. (Why would there be such thing in the first place? It's a clean installation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.

**Update:**

Microsoft fixed the issue within the [update KB4482887](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4482887) (build 17763.348, released on 2019-03-01).
Last time I checked it had to be installed manually and was not available through the server's update feed:

```
~$ wusa.exe kb4482887.msu
```

For more info see [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9d82adb-5dd5-4e43-878c-2e98e00c2943/hyperv-server-2019-rdp-not-working).

Comment: The command is wusa.exe - not wasu.exe

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was due to "Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector" service being disabled.
I enabled it and restarted both services and it started listening on 3389

Answer (score 1):

What about events in the Windows? Is there anything in Windows Event Manager? Maybe it is some sort of Port conflict inside the Windows. Run the following command - "netstat -an" and share the output. Also, you can change the decimal value of the RDP default port and try to log in.

Take a look at Microsoft forum https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c3cfc2df-fc29-4abc-acf1-01797f528333/port-3389-not-listening?forum=winserverTS

There are the problems with some MS driver:

"We opened a case with Microsoft on this issue and we determined that it was related to the following driver being disabled:
remote desktop services security filter driver
To check whether this enabled or disabled, open device manager and show hidden devices. We were not able to enable it, so we uninstalled it and rebooted. After rebooting we were able to telnet to the server on port 3389, but we were still not able to connect with remote desktop.
As a last step, we set remote desktop security layer to “negotiate”. To do this, open the "remote desktop session host configuration" application in administrative tools and edit the properties of “rdp-tcp”. The setting can be found on the general tab.
Hope this helps someone!"

Comment: The question has `netstat` output: Port binding is missing. Also, nothing useful in event log. Tried out everything (except one thing, see below) in the linked thread, nothing worked.
Everything, except the part you quoted.
Concerning "remote desktop services security filter driver": It was hard to even find something out about devices and drivers in the first place without any MMC or GUI available. Using PS cmdlets, I couldn't find a device or driver named like that. Also, I don't know how to open "remote desktop session host configuration". Not sure if included in Hyper-V Server at all?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows usually the port will not listen if you have the "Remote Desktop" section set to "Don't allow remote connections to this computer" under the advanced "System Properties".

To check, do the following:

1. Goto: Start -> Control Panel
2. Select "System"
   3a) If you are using windows prior to Windows-10 then just click on "Advanced System Settings" and you should have a window pop up with "system properties"
   3b) If you are using windows-10 onwards, then you will be taken into the "above" menu, if so, then scroll down and then select "Advanced System Settings".
3. At this stage you should have the "System Properties" window up.
4. Select the "Remote" tab
5. Under "Remote Desktop" ensure you have "Allow Remote Connections to this computer".
   NOTE: If you have it set to "Don't allow..." then the port will NOT listen, regardless of the service being up and firewall enabled, the port will not be listed on the LISTENing ports.
6. Click "Select Users",
7. Enter the user that should connect, this is usually yourself or "administrator". Please DON'T enter "EVERYONE" or add more users than you should as it's insecure and you would be asking for trouble otherwise, well; use common sense.
8. Ok -> Ok
   Should work afterwards.

By default, this is OFF, or sometimes it's on but some corporate admins might disable it for security reasons.

Good luck, and hope all goes well.

Regards,
Heider.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
As stated on another thread (it's not mine solution):
just download the KB from http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4482887

then store it on a USB key and mount it on your Core Server, then from a command prompt install it using:

Wusa KB.msu

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9d82adb-5dd5-4e43-878c-2e98e00c2943/hyperv-server-2019-rdp-not-working?forum=winserverhyperv&prof=required